# Speed of ubuntu samba server is very low

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba, home-server

I am using my Laptop as my home Server. I haved installed  Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS version and using Samba for sharing files. My laptop/server is directly connected with router through LAN cable.
My server spec are:

CPU: i5-7200U

Ram: 4GB
Storage: 500Gb HDD

Ethernet Port: 100 MB/s

I am getting 11 mbs speed on read/write of server. Only one device is connected to server. How can i boost this speed? I even try to replace hdd with ssd but using ssd speed remain same

Here is my **smb.conf**(/etc/samba/smb.conf) config:
I am using [ServerData] directory....

```
[ServerData]
   path = /home/admins/ServerData/
   writeable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   create mask = 0644
   directory mask = 0755
```

Comment: is `11 mbs speed` megabits or megabytes per second?

Comment: you indicate that you have a 100Mbit network card. Max bandwidth on a 100Mbit link is 12.5MB/s. sounds like you are getting good speeds for the hardware you have.

Comment: @JaromandaX 11 mb/s

Comment: @FrankThomas Its 100 Mb/s.
https://i.imgur.com/2R9AUfz.png

Comment: I know you keep writing it mbs or mb/s, but that doesn't clarify what YOU mean by mbs ...  how/where did you measure that in windows? Windows only ever gives speeds in Bytes per second as far as I recall

Comment: since you were able to share a picture of your ethtool output, please share an image of iftop showing that interface while you are transferring a single large file. that should clear up any ambiguities or terminology issues.